# av_read_frame of ffmpeg in windows always returning random packet.stream_index

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, decoder

I'm using ffmpeg to decode an rtsp stream, the av_read_frame is always returning random value on packet.stream_index.

The stream have only 2 index, 1 video and 1 audio respectively on streams[0] and streams[1].

But when i call av_read_frame, i've random value on packet.stream_index and no data in the packet.

If someone can help me, i'm beginner in FFMPEG.

I add my simplified code to make you an idea of what i do :

```
AVFormatContext* input_ctx  = NULL;
AVStream* video_st          = NULL;
AVCodecContext* decoder_ctx = NULL;
AVCodec* decoder;
AVPacket pkt = { 0 };
AVFrame* frame = NULL; 
DWORD dwHeight  =   576;
DWORD dwWidth   =   704;
            
int ret, i;

input_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();

/* open the input file */
ret = avformat_open_input(&input_ctx, "rtsp://**************************/Streaming/Channels/102?profile=Profile_1", NULL, NULL);

avformat_find_stream_info(input_ctx, NULL);

av_dump_format(input_ctx, 0, "rtsp://**************************/Streaming/Channels/102?profile=Profile_1", 0);

av_find_best_stream(input_ctx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, 0, -1, &decoder, 0);

/* find the first H.264 video stream */
for (i = 0; i < input_ctx->nb_streams-1; i++) {
    AVStream *st = input_ctx->streams[i];
    video_st = st;
}

decoder_ctx = input_ctx->streams[0]->codec;

decoder = avcodec_find_decoder(decoder_ctx->codec_id);

decoder_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(decoder);

ret = avcodec_open2(decoder_ctx, NULL, NULL);

frame = av_frame_alloc();

av_read_play(input_ctx);

/* actual decoding */
while (ret >= 0) {
    ret = av_read_frame(input_ctx, &pkt);
        
    if (pkt.stream_index == video_st->index) {
        if ((avcodec_send_packet != NULL)&&(avcodec_receive_frame!=NULL)) { 
            ret = avcodec_send_packet(decoder_ctx, pkt);
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: That’s seems unlikely. What is the return value of av_read_frame when this happenes?

Comment: The return value is 0.